# Is there a Javascript library for creating vintage photos?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

I'm working on a [Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) object in HTML5, and I am attempting to make some photos look "better".

I tried [VintageJS](http://vintagejs.com/), an existing photo-retouching Javascript library, and [Picozu](http://www.picozu.com/), a web application cloning some Adobe Photoshop functionalities, but I'm still not happy.

Can you help me with an algorithm or point to an existing Javascript library that would allow me to make my photos look like the following example?

http://i46.photobucket.com/albums/f137/thanhtu_zx/Untitled-1.jpg
[image: example of a "vintage" look]

Comment: I would call that effect _smoking pot_

Comment: Thanks for display image. the exactly what I need that is an array "RGB-Curves" similar:  https://github.com/rendro/vintageJS/blob/77a05121782469ee3df4cb2bfcfd490bc7e78840/src/vintage.js (line 17)

Comment: @NguyenThanhTu you should create an answer with the link you found.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this post here for sometime without any action, so  I took a gander on the web to see what was there. I also found VintageJS, for vintage photos.

Go figure. Here is the code.

```
$('img.vintage').click(function () {
    $(this).vintage({
        vignette: {
            black: 0.8,
            white: 0.2
        },
        noise: 20,
        screen: {
            red: 12,
            green: 75,
            blue: 153,
            strength: 0.3
        },
        desaturate: 0.05
    });
});
```

[Here are two other similar photo manipulation frameworks: Paintbrush.js and Caman.js, in a nice tutorial with Vintage.js](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153052/is-there-a-javascript-library-for-creating-vintage-photos).

It seems to me that it is all in the implementation.

Try:

vignette:{ black: 0.3, white: .7 },
           noise: 40, screen: { red: 120, green: 65, blue: 133, strength: 0.5 },
           desaturate: 0.15 });

This is a good question; I didn't know these before. Now we do.